# How to Create a Soundboard That Plays Audio Through the Microphone in a Voice Call?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, microphone, input-devices

I’ve been diligently searching for a solution on how to play audio (specifically audio files) through the microphone, but so far, I haven’t had any success. My goal is to create a soundboard – something akin to what you’d find in radio shows or live streams.

I want to develop something like [Soundpad](https://store.steampowered.com/app/629520/Soundpad/):

> Play sounds in voice chats in high digital quality. Add sounds or music to your microphone signal so others will hear it, too.

Let me elaborate further:

**Scenario:** Imagine you’re in a voice call with someone, and you want to play a sound effect (like a funny clip or a catchphrase) for the other person to hear. S0 basically, I'm on a voice call with someone and then I load an audio file into my program and click on a button to play the audio file so that the person on the other end of the call can hear my sound.

**Objective:** I want to achieve this by making applications recognize the sound as if it’s coming directly from the microphone, while still allowing regular input from the mic.

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want your app to be able to use voice or some sound to execute a specific command which would then mix certain audio file with the microphone input. Most difficult part would be implementing this audio recognition. You can get a vague idea of how this works by watching [How Shazam Works (Probably!) - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRsq9apr5QY) video.  While in said video they do talk about song recognition algorithm it is possible to use similar algorithm for recognizing certain sounds like what you seek. ...

Comment: ... Second part which is mixing specific audio files with microphone input might be much easier to implement. Well it depends whether you are making voice call through your application or some third party application. In case of third party application you would want to design your application so that it is receiving microphone audio mix some other audi with it and then transmits the mixed audio through a software output channel. And then the third party app actually selects your application software sound output as its microphone input.

Comment: Imagine this. I'm on a voice call with someone and then I load an audio file into my program and click on a button to play the audio file so that the person on the other end of the call can hear my sound.

Comment: @MartinKakhuis that doesn't change what SilverWarrior said. What you are asking for requires your app to provide its own output channel as the input channel to some other system. If the user's microphone audio goes through your app first, then you can mix whatever you want into your output. But, if you don't have access to the user's input audio, then you can't do what you want.